# combinations of a set with given number elements

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

i have tried to do that but could not figure it out ,

lets say i have a set : `{1,2,3,4,5}`

and i want to have the combinations of 2 elements like :

```
{1,2}
{1,3}
{1,4}
{1,5}
{2,3}
{2,4}
{2,5}
{3,4}
{3,5}
{4,5}
```

how can i implement that in objective-c?

i have checked the algorithms but i could not figure out how can i do that..
here's the main url that i have checked previously : [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

if anyone could help me with that i will be really happy..

regards.

Comment: did something from that answer not work for you?

Comment: yeah but only for 2 elemented combination. i need a generic code that will work for "n" elemented combinations..

Comment: I believe the answers from your link work for the general case, though I guess i'm not dead certain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a nested loop to walk over the array's elements and writing the combinations to a result array should work (this code is tested and works):

```
NSArray *set = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1],
                [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2],
                [NSNumber numberWithInteger:3],
                [NSNumber numberWithInteger:4],
                [NSNumber numberWithInteger:5], nil];

NSMutableArray *combinations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSInteger i=0; i<[set count]; i++) {
    for(NSInteger j=i+1; j<[set count]; j++){
        NSArray *newCombination = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                   [set objectAtIndex:i],
                                   [set objectAtIndex:j],
                                   nil];
        [combinations addObject:newCombination];
        NSLog(@"added combination %@", newCombination);
    }
}
```

At the end of this nested loop, NSMutableArray **combinations** contains all your combinations.

Comment: thank you so much , i have an array of items but i will use the i'th and the j'th elements so i will have the required combinations..

Comment: but i have a problem right now , if i want to get 3 element possibilities than i need to use them in a while loop? here starts my problem again :) how can i implement this?

Comment: add one more for loop with k=i+2

Comment: Like sshekhar says, one more loop ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using 2 `for-loop`s. In the first loop, you iterate through the elements as `i` and in the second loop from the value `j=i+1` to the end of the count of the number of elements in the set.

It could be something like this:

```
 for (i = 0; i < length_set; i++)
{
    for (j = i + 1;length_set; j++)
    {
        print ("%d%d\n", set[i], set[j]);
    }
}
```

}

**NOTE:** Its just a pseudocode and i have not checked for syntax, It is just to show the logic.

Comment: Wrap the for loop in a recursive function or method and it can call itself based on the number of elements needed.